# Does populating a UITableView with an NSMutableArray maintain the order?

Tags: ios, uitableview, view, nsmutablearray

I want to fill a table view with items from a mutable array, in the order they were.
Before I inserted them, I was logging the array's values to make sure they were in the correct order - and they were - but then after I use:

```
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:dictOrder withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

The items appear to be in a jumbled order (which is the same every time)

Edit: Had no idea that the objects in my array (which is used in some of the table view methods) were automatically put into the tableview. Thanks for your contributions!

Comment: What is `dictOrder`? Based on what you are trying to accomplish `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:` may not be what you want. What is the original array and what is the result you are getting?

Comment: An array populated with some strings

Comment: Add more information to the question: an example array and the result and what you are trying to accomplish. –  Zaph 6 mins ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` takes an `NSArray` of `NSIndexPath` objects not an array of `NSString` objects.

What are you trying to accomplish?

Possibly what you want is the `UITableViewDataSource` method: `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to populate the `UITableView` display with the values from the `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: Yep, I have no idea what this function I was using does, but I needed to populate the cells, so I'll iterate through my array adding to the table with the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. Thanks!